# Cisco 2960 switch mode access cannot assign IP address for virtual machine

Tags: cisco, virtual-machines, dhcp, switch, vmware-workstation

we are testing the VMware setup in our lab. We have a 2960 switch connect to a PC. Inside the PC, we have VMware workstation 11 installed. When I setup the NIC of Virtual machine (Win7) as NAT, it can automatically be assigned an IP address, but if I setup it as Bridge, nothing shows up. On 2960 switch, that port was configured as access mode, a real PC can have valid IP address but VMware. DHCP pool with 254 valid IP address is Ok. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Have you set port security? Bridge mode means  that the VM will use it's on (virtual) NIC with mac address different from the host machine. If you have port security on the port the host is connected, with a limit of 1 mac address, only the host machine will have connectivity. The guest will not. In NAT mode however, the guest will have connectivity, because it uses the hosts' layer 2 address.

Comment: @13nilux Thanks for your reply. There is no any security configuration in that port. Any other idea you can suggest?